# Compressing sql rows for oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I'm having trouble figuring out how to correctly merge rows. Looking at the sample table below:

```
TYPE  | NAME   | COLOR | DESCRIPTION
=================================
Fruit | Apple  | Red   | -----    
Fruit | Apple  | ----- | sweet    
Fruit | Orange | ----- | ripe
```

What I want to do is merge the rows 1 and 2 so that rows with the same type and name will have a single row and its values be merged as one row.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How large is the dataset?  Not sure about with just SQL, but with some kind of programming language, that just involves a hash table and heavy amount of deleting/updating.  (I'm assuming you mean merge permanently?)

Comment: Forgot to state that this dataset is returned by a query. Just can't figure out how to merge rows. The columns could also expand based on users' input.

Comment: Is it always an empty and non empty row or will content need to be merged?

Comment: yes. But only for the rows with the same type and name

Comment: Assuming they are non-null (though I could be wrong on that as I'm not intimately familiar with Oracle), Justin Cave's answer should work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT type, 
       name, 
       MAX(color) color, 
       MAX(description) description
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY type, name;
```